# SDL2 Window lacking window bar

Tags: c, macos, sdl, sdl-2

[image]

I'm trying to build an SDL2 app on OSX El Capitan, and I am running into an issue where the window dressing is not appearing. Things like the exit button and the resizing bar are not appearing. I've compiled on Windows and it all works fine there.

To make it a bit easier this link to Lazy Foo's tutorial replicates the issue: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php

My make file is pretty simple (I've stolen it off his website as well)

```
COMPILER_FLAGS = -w

LINKER_FLAGS = -framework SDL2

#OBJS specifies which files to compile as part of the project
OBJS = main.c 
#CC specifies which compiler we're using
CC = g++

OBJ_NAME = main
#This is the target that compiles our executable
all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, I'd love to find out.

UPDATE: I pulled out an old laptop, fresh installed to El Capitan and it is having the same issue based on the Lazy Foo code.

UPDATE:

```
/*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2015)
and may not be redistributed without written permission.*/

//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

            //Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

            //Wait two seconds
            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of the root cause but making a loop that polls events seems to do the trick.

```
bool loop = true;
while(loop)
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            loop = false;
        }
    }
}
```